# Error generating PMD report in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I've tried to generate an XML report by
right-clicking the `project > PMD> Generate Reports`

After which this error dialog box appears.

```
An internal error occurred during: "RenderReport". java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help. How to fix this?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.Anyone know What is the issue.I am using Luna Service Release 2 - Version 4.4.2